# MySQL Select Where Unexpected Results

Tags: mysql, select, joomla, denormalized

I have a Joomla (3.9.13) database that contains a table called `fields_values`, it is a denormalized key value store (so i've been told). It contains the following data;

```
+----------+---------+--------+
| field_id | item_id | value  |
+----------+---------+--------+
| 6        | 119     | bloggs |
| 17       | 119     | 1      |
| 19       | 119     | 45     |
| 21       | 119     | 55     |
| 17       | 119     | 14     |
| 17       | 119     | 100    |
+----------+---------+--------+
```

When I run this query;

```
SELECT `field_id`
     , `item_id`
     , `value` 
  FROM `fields_values` 
 WHERE `field_id` IN (6,17) AND `item_id` = '119'
```

I get these results;

```
+----------+---------+--------+
| field_id | item_id | value  |
+----------+---------+--------+
| 6        | 119     | bloggs |
| 17       | 119     | 1      |
| 17       | 119     | 2      |
| 17       | 119     | 13     |
| 17       | 119     | 14     |
| 17       | 119     | 100    |
+----------+---------+--------+
```

That all seems fine, but when I run this query (omit the `6` from `IN` clause);

```
SELECT `field_id`
     , `item_id`
     , `value` 
  FROM `fields_values` 
 WHERE `field_id` IN (17) AND `item_id` = '119'
```

I get **zero** results.

I would have expected the following results;

```
+----------+---------+--------+
| field_id | item_id | value  |
+----------+---------+--------+
| 17       | 119     | 1      |
| 17       | 119     | 2      |
| 17       | 119     | 13     |
| 17       | 119     | 14     |
| 17       | 119     | 100    |
+----------+---------+--------+
```

I've also tried this simple version of the query;

```
SELECT 
    `field_id`, 
    `item_id`, 
    `value` 
FROM 
    `o3m0z_fields_values` 
WHERE
    `field_id` = 17 
AND 
    `item_id` = '119'
```

I get **zero** results.

Here's the table information taken from HeidiSQL;

[image]

I've tried to replicate this on a fresh Joomla install and I can't. Why is this happening?

Note: I can't change the query as it's generated by the core Joomla system.

Comment: Can't replicate https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/krkchC29r8eBxDimraey3x/0

Comment: Likewise, can't replicate.

Comment: What happens if you comment out ``` AND `item_id` = '119' ``` part?

Comment: Cross-posted here: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/26559/12352

Comment: @Nick that is not exactly the schema we are dealing with.  Notice that jonboy's `item_id` is `VARCHAR`.  I am suspicious of potentially overlooked spaces / invisible characters lurking _somewhere_.

Comment: @mickmackusa schema makes no difference https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/krkchC29r8eBxDimraey3x/1. Without seeing the joomla code I guess it's possible spaces/hidden characters are being inserted into the query, but why would a fresh install solve the problem?

Comment: I don't recommend a fresh install.  I also tried changing the schema.  I also tried it on postgre.  To no avail.  I am running out of possible causes. If jonboy proves that there are no invisible characters, then I may have to tap RickJames to come and stick his nose in here. @Nick

Comment: In case volunteers don't want to chase link to link for more info, this is the environment: `Joomla 3.9.13`, `PHP version: 7.3.9`, `Mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.6-MariaDB`